# Endpoint URL unreachable ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://glue.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am looking to get all tables from Glue database.
Below is my AWS Glue Job script

```
next_token = ""
client = boto3.client('glue',region_name='ap-south-1')
table_list = []

while True:
  response = client.get_tables(DatabaseName = 'postgresql_processed', NextToken = next_token)
  for tables in response['TableList']:
      table_list.append(tables['Name'])
  next_token = response.get('NextToken')
  if next_token is None:
    break
print(table_list)
```

But I am getting an error Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://glue.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/".
I dont want to use any Endpoint for this.

Comment: "I dont want to use any Endpoint for this." - what do you mean by this?

Comment: @Marcin I am running the script inside glue job. I read somewhere that I need to create Dev endpoints in GLue. But that costs me more money... I just want to get the table name in a list from glue database.